# Cross-db references not allowed in dbt-oracle

Tags: oracle, dbt

after running `dbt docs generate` I ran into a runtime error:

```
Encountered an error while generating catalog: Runtime Error
  Cross-db references not allowed in oracle (db1 vs db2)
```

[image]

The docs get generate nonetheless but the command finishes with an error. For some reason it always checks the default target database from `profiles.yml` against other connections.

Why does it try to execute this cross-db references?